Generating SAS URL for Azure Blob Container with Proper Permissions
I'm attempting to generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL for an Azure Blob storage container using Python and the Azure SDK. The SAS token is successfully generated, but when I try to use it to upload a file to the container, I encounter an "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" error.
def generate_sas_url_for_container(strg_account, credentials, container_name, permissions, validity_hours):
    try:
        # Create BlobServiceClient using the storage account name and credentials
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{strg_account}.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credentials)

        # Define permissions for the SAS token
        container_permissions = ContainerSasPermissions(read=permissions.read, create=permissions.create, list=permissions.list)
        user_delegation_key = blob_service_client.get_user_delegation_key(datetime.utcnow(), datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))

        # Define expiry for the SAS token
        expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=validity_hours)

        # Generate SAS token for the container
        sas_token = generate_container_sas(
            account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
            user_delegation_key=user_delegation_key,
            container_name=container_name,
            account_key=None,
            permission=container_permissions,
            expiry=expiry,
            sv="2020-08-04"
        )
        sas_url = f"https://{blob_service_client.account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}?{sas_token}"
        return sas_url
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating SAS URL for container: {e}")
        return None

And here's the error message I'm encountering when trying to use the generated SAS URL to upload a file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:a6cfe60c-501e-0095-40bf-a00
Time:2024-05-14T05:26:24.9759212Z</Message></Error>



encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This
request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
permission. RequestId:a6cfe60c-501e-0095-40bf-a00
Time:2024-05-14T05:26:24.9759212Z</Message></Error> ```


The above error occurs when you don't have proper permission to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage.
You can use the code below to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage with correct permissions using generated sas url.
Corrected Code:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, generate_container_sas, ContainerSasPermissions
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def generate_sas_url_for_container(strg_account, credentials, container_name, permissions, validity_hours):
    try:
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{strg_account}.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credentials)
        user_delegation_key = blob_service_client.get_user_delegation_key(datetime.utcnow(), datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
        expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=validity_hours)
        sas_token = generate_container_sas(
            account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
            user_delegation_key=user_delegation_key,
            container_name=container_name,
            permission=permissions,
            expiry=expiry,
            protocol="https"
        )
        sas_url = f"https://{blob_service_client.account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas_token}"
        return sas_url
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating SAS URL for container: {e}")
        return None

def upload_file_to_container_with_sas_url(sas_url_with_blob_name, file_path):
    try:
        blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url_with_blob_name)
        with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error uploading file to container: {e}")
        return False

strg_account = "venkat123"
container_name = "test"
file_path = r"C:\Users\Downloads\important.png"
blob_name = "sample.png"
permissions = ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, delete=True, list=True)
validity_hours = 1
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

sas_url_with_blob_name = generate_sas_url_for_container(strg_account, credentials, container_name, permissions, validity_hours)
upload_file_to_container_with_sas_url(sas_url_with_blob_name, file_path)

The above code is executed and the file is uploaded using the sas url.
Output:


Hi, Thanks for your code. Although i only need to generated SAS URL with python and that SAS URL is being used as some other place to upload file. So blob_name is not applicable here. and with your code, the URL that is getting generated gives below error:
<Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>


@Mr.Annonymous The above code will generate container url and you can manually add the blob name which you want to upload.

As a user what are the rbac roles in the portal?

You need storage blob data contributor role to generate sas token using user delegation key.

Please Update the question how you uploading the file with url?

HI @venkatesan, i am generating credentials with Azure AD Application and the Application has Contributor access to storage account.
After generating the SAS URL, i am sending it to Java code to upload the file.

can you share sas url you are getting?

Sure, will hide few values
https://testt.blob.core.windows.net/test?se=2025-03-04T22%3A25%3A42Z&sp=Namespace%28read%3DTrue%2C%20c
reate%3DTrue%2C%20list%3DTrue%29&spr=https&sv=2021-08-06&sr=c&skoid=1c9bd-ca3c-4eda-b328-4779&sktid=92
7-8876-4dcb-a6c0-994a3&skt=2024-05-14T08%3A25%3A40Z&ske=2024-05-14T09%3A25%3A40Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=xYl%2BH0r4nRLW7uUHYFKVAAktVPk4MvQTGHcDc%3D


The container sas url should be like this https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/?se=2024-05-14T09%3A56%3A25Z&sp=rwdl&spr=https&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&skoid=6e19aa9e-1e69-4a85-85f4-b00099a8da5c&sktid=72fxxxf-91ab-2d7cd011db47&skt=2024-05-14T08%3A56%3A22Z&ske=2024-05-14T09%3A56%3A22Z&sks=b&skv=2023-11-03&sig=RKfUxXxxxxxxuQ%3D

please add java code how you uploading with container sas url in the question..

Let me know whether you facing any errors.

let me try, wil let you know

Using your provided code, i am getting:
AuthorizationPermissionMismatchThis request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
i used service principal instead of default credentials

Please assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role to your aad application then run the code

working fine. Can you we create until container level only?

Already it is container level sastoken only you can upload different file.

If i can blob_name from the SAS URL and then generate it? will it work?

Yes it will work:)
